# Why can't I view the value of a string property in the Xcode debugger variable window?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am having problem with following code

```
mediaFile.artist = [track artist];             

if(mediaFile.artist == nil || [mediaFile.artist isEqualToString:@""])
{
    // value 'unknown' is not assigned , when I see in the debugger
    mediaFile.artist = @"unknown";
}
```

The property artist in the class MediaFile is deaclared and defined like this

```
// In MediaFile class
//property defined in MediaFile  header
@property (retain) NSString* artist;

// in MediaFile.m file
@synthesize artist = _artist;
```

When the `[track artist]` returns a good value which is not empty then I can see the value stored in the `mediafile.artist` property, but when it returns nil or empty the code that assigns `@"unknown"` runs, the pointer changes for `mediafile.artist` as I notice in the debugger, but the values `"unknown"` is not visible. Any ideas?

Edit:
po [mediaFile artist] shows the value but debugger variable window shows only pointer and not the string value

Comment: What happens when you do `po [mediaFile artist]`?

Comment: don't know where to do that, I am looking at the window that shows variables to the left of output, do I need to put po [mediaFile artist] in code ? or some interactive window of debugger ? I am new to objective c

Comment: it return correct value there - 0x000000010000e958 unknown but Why not it shows in the variables window ? -

Comment: are you confirmed that the `if` statement is getting executed/

Answer (score 0):

Properties that are not explicitly backed by ivars do not show up in the debugger. If you need to see them, you can explicitly declare the ivar in your .h file, like this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSString* _artist;
}
```

Then, declare your `@property` and synthesize it as usual. It should appear in the debugger.

Comment: Well, I am going to try it, but one thing for sure if in my code sample [track artist] returns a non empty value then it does show in the debugger. Only if literal is assigned then it does not show